# Google Map Direction using comgooglemaps

Tags: ios, google-maps, directions

I am using google map directions 
I am trying that code but it doesn't work

```
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
```

There is always message that "Can't use comgooglemaps://
Is There any additional setting to use this. I have read google doc but there is not such instructions to use any additional setting

Comment: Do you have the native Google Maps installed on your device? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8

Comment: @Asaf   No I have not

Comment: You must have this app installed in order for this `URL Scheme` to work. Otherwise, you can use the `http://maps.google.com/.....` and it will open it in the browser.

Comment: Just trying it and let u know after that

Comment: One thing Its not comming back to my Application, it just navigation back to application of google map

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question

Comment: I am using Now   NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL]) {
        NSString *directionsRequest = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=myappnameinurlscheme.plistfile";
        NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsRequest];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
    } else {
      
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80766/discussion-between-zohaib-khan-niazi-and-asaf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order for this `URL Scheme` to work you need to have the Google Maps app installed.
2. If you want to use the callback option, you need your app to respond to some `URL Scheme`. In order to do so, [please check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html). After that, pass your custom url scheme in the `x-success` parameter.

Comment: Its working . Just for other  I replace SourceApp with my urlscheme defined than it is wokring.

Comment: I am currently doing something like this in my RN app: ```Linking.canOpenURL(
          'comgooglemaps://?center=53.140027, 8.2181037',)```. Would it work if I just use ```Linking.canOpenURL( 'comgooglemaps://')```. I just want to check if google maps can be opened or not. But I don't have it installed in my simulator so can't check.